# Is there a way to make Batik compatible with CSS3 styling?

Tags: css, svg, batik

I'm wanting to convert an SVG to PNG/JPG using Java, and most of the results point to using Batik.

However, the problem I'm having is that Batik seems to not play well with CSS style functions.

Here's a sample SVG I'm trying to convert:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="graphdiagram" viewBox="-642.5 -415 1285 830">
    <g class="layer relationships"/>
    <g class="layer nodes">
        <circle class="node node-id-0" r="19.7810942818944" fill="rgb(247, 247, 249)" stroke="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039)" stroke-width="0.909091px" cx="0" cy="0"/>
        <g class="caption">
            <text class="caption node" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" x="0" y="0" fill="rgb(51, 51, 51)" font-size="14px" font-family="'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Foo</text>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g class="layer properties"/>
    <g class="layer overlay">
        <circle class="node overlay" r="20.235639781894402" stroke="none" fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)" cx="0" cy="0"/>
        <circle class="node ring" r="25.235639781894402" fill="none" stroke="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)" stroke-width="10px" cx="0" cy="0"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Batik will throw errors like:

```
ERROR: null
Enclosed Exception:
http://www.w3.org/2000/svg:
The attribute "stroke" represents an invalid CSS value ("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039)").
Original message:
The "stroke" property does not support function values.

***** CSSEngine: exception property.syntax.error:org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "stroke" property does not support function values.

AttrValue:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039)
```

Is there a simple way to get Batik to work well with CSS3 syntax - or am I going to have a write a parsing function to manually set the stroke-opacity etc?

Comment: It's open source. Download it and add support.

Comment: check their doc list on https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/, they also have a mailing list

Answer (score 3):

If Batik doesn't support rgba colour values, then as a workaround, use `stroke-opacity` and/or `fill-opacity` as appropriate.

So instead of:

```
stroke="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039)"
```

you can use:

```
stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-opacity="0.298039"
```

Comment: Yup, this does look like the solution I'm using, but there are other css3 functions that I also have to replace.

Comment: With `fill-opacity` you mean `opacity` I guess: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/opacity

Comment: @S.Doe No I mean [fill-opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-opacity).